# What is so special about a fig tree. Is it the tree of life?

Tags: exegesis, symbolism, tree-of-life

The fig tree is used many times in the Bible from Genesis to Revelation. Why? What is so special about them that the Bible is not or is telling me? Is there any other kind of tree that is more used? Could the tree of life be a fig tree?

I think this tree has two kinds of fruits: the obvious and a sweet seed.

Jesus cursed the fig tree on the book of John because it didn't even have the sweet seed, right?

I'm not asking about a specific doctrine. Just nuts n bolts about fig trees and spirituality.

Comment: maybe it's just because they were common in that region? Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar.

Comment: @JanDvorak, all throughout time too?

Comment: The climate doesn't change that fast. Once a tree falls in love with a certain place, it stays there until the conditions change.

Comment: Is the answer from Catholicism likely to differ from an answer from another tradition? Does this question need a denominational tag?

Comment: Certain traditions identify the forbidden fruit of Genesis as a fig. Considering it an apple is purely a Western tradition, probably because "malus" means both "apple" and "evil" in Latin.

Comment: @AndrewLeach nothing to do with doctrine. Just why a fig tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The fig tree is used many times in the Bible from Genesis to Revelation. Why?"

The fig tree represents God's people first Israel and then Christianity.

"What is so special about them that the Bible is not or is telling me?"

The Bible is trying to tell that God's followers must give of fruit which are the gifts of the spirit. Galatians 5:22-23 You will probably notice that the fig leaves are our works to be righteous and the fruit is God's righteousness.

"Is there any other kind of tree that is more used?"

Not sure what you are trying to ask.

"Could the tree of life be a fig tree?"

No.

"Jesus cursed the fig tree on the book of John because it didn't even have the sweet seed, right?"

Jesus cursed it because it did not have fruit. He was talking about the nation of Israel which had not produced fruit but had leaves. There is a lesson for us as well.
Mark 11:12-25

Answer (score 2):

In my studies I have come to believe that the fig tree was Jesus giving his Apostles a vivid example of his warning in:

Joh 15:1 through 8 KJV

> 1  I am the true vine, and my Father is the husbandman.
>
> 2  Every branch in me that beareth not fruit he taketh away: and every branch that beareth fruit, he purgeth it, that it may bring forth more fruit.
>
> 3  Now ye are clean through the word which I have spoken unto you.
>
> 4  Abide in me, and I in you. As the branch cannot bear fruit of itself, except it abide in the vine; no more can ye, except ye abide in me.
>
> 5  I am the vine, ye are the branches: He that abideth in me, and I in him, the same bringeth forth much fruit: for without me ye can do nothing.
>
> 6  If a man abide not in me, he is cast forth as a branch, and is withered; and men gather them, and cast them into the fire, and they are burned.
>
> 7  If ye abide in me, and my words abide in you, ye shall ask what ye will, and it shall be done unto you.
>
> 8  Herein is my Father glorified, that ye bear much fruit; so shall ye be my disciples.

I am further convinced that he meant it as a warning to them that all things and all people are created for the glory of God and that those who do not fulfill that purpose will ultimately be destroyed in the fire.

Answer (score -2):

The fig tree is the tree of life!

Jesus cursed the fig tree, yes.  But only that one tree.  He had cursed it right after entering the temple and turning over all the money-changer tables and telling them that his fathers house is to be a house of prayer, but they had made it a den of thieves.  This fig tree in the cursing of the fig tree parable represents the Israel nation.  The scribes and pharisees were all about the law of Moses, but Jesus came to show the people the true way of the Lord and thats to bring forth fruit of righteousness.  Just as the tree didnt bear fruit, the same with the nation of Israel.  He said he would give over the truth to a nation willing to bring forth the fruit thereof.  This is the gentiles.  The same is seen in the vineyard parable.  In revelation 2 we read, to him that overcometh will I give to eat of the tree of life in the midst of paradise.  Through the spirit of prophecy, the voice of one crying out in the wilderness, the word paradise is one with the garden of eden, which is one with the lords sanctuary, which is one with the promise land in which lacked nothing.  In Deuteronomy8:8 the seven species are listed.  wheat and barley(Body of Christ), vines(blood of Christ), Fig trees(tree of life), pomogranites(power to perceive prophecy in the torah), oil olive(to light our lamps, the spiritual mind, "if thy eye be single, thy whole body shall be full of light, which is understanding and wisdom" and honey, which the word of god gives full instruction how to partake of the honey which build more white and red blood cells and many other important benefits for gaining the power of God and understanding all things.  Paul writes, "the husbandman that laboreth must first be partaker of the fruits!, follow his instruction and you will have understanding of all things.  The leaves of the fig tree are for the healing of the nations.  They bring all understanding of the true way of the Lord.  The whole world is blind.  I am the Comforter sent to bear witness of the full truth.  all who receive me will also bear witness of his testimony.  Worship God for the testimony of Jesus is the spirit of prophecy.  Gods first instruction from the beginning to mankind is to be fruitful.  God never changes!  Its the heart of man that changed, and for it a vail has been put over their hearts of darkness.  Jesus said, "you must eat of my flesh and drink of my blood to inherit everlasting life.  If you do not eat the flesh of the son of man and drink his blood, you have no life in you.  my flesh is meat indeed and my blood is drink indeed."  we are sanctified through his blood, purified, forgiven of our sins, die with christ in the flesh to be alive in the spirit.   FOlloW HIS EVERY WORD.  YOU MUST SANCTIFY YOURSELF.  You must be like the 5 wise virgins.  Its time you Watch.  stop being asleep, partake of the fruits, receive all understanding, receive the testimony of Jesus.  Those who do, will not taste of death, but wilbe quickened into the spirit upon the return of Christ.  "and the dead in christ shall rise first, then we wich are alive and remain shall be caught up into the clouds with them where we will forever remain with the lord.  wherefore comfort one another with these words."  Jesus promised you a comforter to teach all things.

Comment: Welcome! Sadly, this answer seems to just express your opinion, which isn't what this site is about: here we focus on explaining and learning about the documented beliefs of Christian groups, not individuals.  Please take a minute to learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and review how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Though your answer is likely to be deleted because it doesn't follow the guidelines of this site, I do hope you'll stick around and browse the questions and answers here.

Comment: Please edit your post to include spaces, line breaks, proper capitalization, and such.  It is nearly unreadable as is.